# C++: Iterating through objects to call the same method

Tags: c++, oop, object, foreach, iteration

In C++, say you have a whole bunch of objects that you want to call the same method.

```
Alice->callSameMethod();
Bob->callSameMethod();
...
Yoyo->callSameMethod();
```

But it's troublesome to type the same line from Alice to Yoyo. Is there a way to do something like:

```
For (each x in {Alice,Bob, ..., Yoyo}) x->callSameMethod;
```

I saw for_each over here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/
but didn't understand it.

Comment: Are these objects in an array or standard library container?

Comment: And are they of the same type or base type ?

Comment: Again: If they're not, you should make them.

Comment: Thank you. great answers from everyone. i still prefer the way iteration is done in python though; so much more straightforward and intuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
class Base{public: virtual int callSameMethod() = 0;};
           //pure virtual, can make it a default implementation
class Alice: public Base {public: int callSameMethod();...}; // own implementation
class Bob: public Base {public: int callSameMethod();...}; // own implementation
class YoYo: public Base{public: int callSameMethod();...}; // own implementation
```

Somewhere in your code:

```
Base* p1 = new Alice();
Base* p2 = new Bob();

std::vector<Base*> v;
std::vector<Base*>::iterator it;
v.push_back(p1);
v.push_back(p2);
for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++) (*it)->callSameMethod();
```

This is called "polymorphism", and your base class defines the common interface by which you can call any of the derivatives without knowing which kind exactly they are. You can use `std::for_each` instead of a simple loop, or use the `vector` with indexed access instead of iterators, whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

All objects must have a common base type or be of the same type.

```
class Base { public: virtual void callSameMethod() = 0; }; // abstract base
class Derived1 : public Base { public: virtual void callSameMethod() {:::}; };
class Derived2 : public Base { public: virtual void callSameMethod() {:::}; };

// instances
Base* Alice = new Derived1;
Base* Bob   = new Derived2;
Base* YoYo  = new Derived1;
```

If you have this the most elegant solution depends on your version of C++.

In **C++03** you can create a container that includes pointers to all elements

```
Base* const list[] = {Alice, Bob, YoYo};
```

and iterate over it using an ordinary for loop

```
int length = (sizeof(list) / sizeof(Base*));
for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i) list[i]->callSameMethod();
```

or std::for_each

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

std::for_each(list, list + length, std::mem_fun(&Base::callSameMethod));
```

I discourage the use of an std::vector in this case. The vector forces you to use an overly verbose syntax for initialization and iteration and will be much slower too.

If you have a compiler that supports **C++11** however there is a much simpler solution:

```
#include <initializer_list>

for (auto i : {Alice, Bob, YoYo}) i->callSameMethod();
```

Note that all elements in the initializer list must be of the same pointer type, `Base*`. If this is not the case, the type of the initializer list must be explicitly stated:

```
// alternative declarations with different pointer types
Derived1* Alice = new Derived1;
Derived2* Bob   = new Derived2;
Derived1* YoYo  = new Derived1;

auto objects = std::initializer_list<Base*>{Alice, Bob, YoYo};
for (auto i : objects) i->callSameMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need all objects holding "callSameMethod()" to inherit a same interface where "callSameMethod()" is a virtual function. So you can use "for_each" to do what you want. By the way, you need a functor, too.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing can be done if they're polymorphic. If they all inherit from the same class (which they probably should if they all have common methods), then you can store them all in an `std::vector` of pointers of the base class type. Then it is simply a matter of looping through the vector and calling this method.

i.e.

```
for ( std::vector<BaseClass*>::iterator it = objectsVec.begin(); 
                                        it != objectsVec.end();
                                        ++it )
{
    (*it)->callSameMethod();
}
```